# Critique my proof? Proving f(x) is continuous at x = 0 for a defined function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

We have a problem to solve:

Let $f(x)$ = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{when $x = 0$} \\
x\sin(\frac1x), & \text{when $x\not=0$}
\end{cases}

Prove $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

- My attempt:

$\lvert x\sin(\frac1x) - 0\rvert = \lvert x \rvert \lvert \sin(\frac1x) \rvert \le \lvert x \rvert$ when $x\not=0$ because $\sin$ is always $\le 1$.

We will refer to the inequality immediately above as (*). We can say:

For all $\epsilon \gt 0$, let $\delta = \epsilon$ then (*) $ \lt \delta = \epsilon$

Comment: You cannot assume that $f(x_n)=0$ for all $x_n$ with $|x-x_n|<\delta$. Also, you fail to actually exhibit a $\delta>0$ for given $\epsilon>0$ (you merely repeat your wishlist)

Comment: LOL! You're right. This proof is useless. Thank you! Can you stay tuned for my next proof? I had two drafted I'll just edit this one to state my second proof.

Comment: I had the imprssion that you wanted to go with the epsilon-delta definition. So dot it.

Comment: What is the *informal* reason that the function is continuous at $0$? That comes first, even if one does not write it down.

Comment: I'm even shaky on just that @AndréNicolas. I wouldn't be confident, but I'd say that the function is continuous at 0 since the function becomes infinitely small as x approaches 0 and is defined to be 0 at 0.

Comment: Yes, more or less. If $x$ is close to $0$, and non-zero, then $|x\sin(1/x)|$ is close to $0$, because $|\sin(1/x)|\le 1$.

Comment: Okay guys, I just edited my post to state my second attempt.

Comment: Overall pretty good. As a matter of style I would start by saying something like let $\epsilon\gt 0$ be given. We will show that there is a $\delta\gt 0$ such that $\dots$. Then set up ($\ast$)  as you did, and  continue by saying let $\delta=\epsilon$. If $0\lt |x-0|\lt \delta$, then by ($\ast$)  $|f(x)-0|\lt \delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas this is good advice. thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. You are reasonably good at using text instead of cramming symbols together, but a little more text helps the reader. It also helps you to retain control of the logic. But to repeat, it was basically fine already.

Answer (score 1):

What about $x$ near but not equal to zero? If the second part of the definition of that function was $1$ would you still claim the function is continuous? I don't think it would be in that case.